# Split an array of date times into sub dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, time, split

I have a simple data set that contains an array of times that are separated into 3 hour chunks:

```
0: Wed Dec 04 2013 12:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
1: Wed Dec 04 2013 15:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
2: Wed Dec 04 2013 18:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
3: Wed Dec 04 2013 21:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
4: Thu Dec 05 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
5: Thu Dec 05 2013 03:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
6: Thu Dec 05 2013 06:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
7: Thu Dec 05 2013 09:00:00 GMT-0800 (PST)
```

What I need to do is loop through this array and create a new array that adds in the "missing" hours. So ideally the new array would be an array of 21 new date objects, separated out by each hour.

**Edit:** 
Tried looping through each item in the array, and then looping through 3 times within there and try to create a new date and push it into a new array. But I'm stuck there.

Comment: and what have you tried? why didn't it work?

Comment: If it is sequential, then pick the first item in the array, pick the last item in the array and create a new array with one hour difference dates from the first to last. Also, it would be nice if you created a fiddle and showed us.

Answer (score 0):

After some snooping and researching some date stuff, was able to figure out what I needed to do. (open to suggestions if there are better ways to do this)

```
var oldArrayLength = oldArray.length;
var newArray = [];
for (var i = 0; i < oldArrayLength; i++) {
    for( var j = 0; j < 3; j++ ) {
        var theNewTime = new Date(oldArray[i]);
        theNewTime.setHours(theNewTime.getHours() + j);
        newArray.push(theNewTime);
    }
}
```